# Customize can't be left blank error message in a specific model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called 'Video'

In that model, there is a video_cid, which validates for presence.

In the form this is a hidden field that is updated with a value when someone records a video.

Currently, when a user does not save a video, I am able to produce the error message ==>

```
Video can't be blank
```

**Is there a way I can change this sentence completely?** I'd like it to say->

```
It looks like the video has not been saved. Please record and save your video.
```

I was able to change the name of Video Cid, to 'Video', using the locales/en.yml file

Here's my Video Model :

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: videos
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  user_id    :integer
#  video_cid  :string(255)
#  question   :string(255)
#  created_at :datetime
#  updated_at :datetime
#

class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user

 validates  :user_id, presence: true
 validates  :question, presence: true
 validates  :video_cid, presence: true

end
```

Here's my locales/en.yml file :

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      video:
        video_cid:         "Video"
```

Comment: Please consider marking proper answer as accepted in your previous question before asking new one.

Comment: Hiya, you guys rock! Thank you, and acceptance given :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
validates  :video_cid, :presence => {:message => "It looks like the video has not been saved. Please record and save your video."}
```